# Quantifying the chance of success based on proporions

Tags: probability

Firstly, just to be clear, this is not homework, it's just me playing around with some numbers I saw in an article regarding equality in recruitment, more specifically, for one industry, the following percentages where given

- 31% of all applicants were women
- 47% of all hires were women

So, intuitively, this tells us women chat the chance of a woman being successful is greater of that of a man being successful. But, i thought it would be interesting to try and quantify that.

Assigning assigning some numbers to the problem, for example, if we had 100 applicants, 31 women and 69 men, and say ,10 open jobs, then 4.7 jobs go to women and 5.3 job goes to men, and thus we'd have

$$
P(S_w) = \frac{4.7}{31} \approx 0.15 \\
P(S_m) = \frac{5.3}{69} \approx 0.08
$$

where $S_w$ is the probability that an woman applying is successsful, and $S_m$ is the probability of a man applying being successful. Ofcourse, these probabilities are a function of the numbers choosen, when picking the number of applicant and the number of available jobs.

I'm wondering what the correct way of dealing with this is? I tried thinking of the problem as
$P(S_w) = P(H_w | A_w)$, where $H_w$ is the chance a woman is hired and $A_w$ is the probability that a woman applied. With $H_w$ and $A_w$ being dependant events, and $P(H_w)$. But this seems wrong, as I end up with

$$
P(H_w | A_w) = \frac{P(H_W \cap A_w)}{P(A_w)}
$$
which is greater than 1 if i define treat $P(H_W \cap A_w) = 0.47$.

So, in short, what would be the best way of identifying $P(S_w)$ and $P(S_m)$?

Comment: Without having information on the number of jobs, it is hard to say much.  Say there were only two jobs and one woman got hired, as did one man.  Then $50\%$ of the hires were women.  But if there were hundreds of applicants (of either gender) then any applicant's success probability would be near $0$. Or, maybe every female applicant got hired, with enough male applicants being hired to true up the numbers.  Can't tell from the simple percent data.

Comment: Should say:  I don't understand your events $H_w, A_w$.  Are you looking at a particular woman here?  If so, then we have no idea what the probability that a randomly selected woman applies.  I think the obvious notions should be used:  The success rate for women should be the number of women who get hired divided by the number of women who apply.

Comment: Hi Lulu, thanks for your comment. this was basically where I started. the number of women hired versus the number of women applied. I got a little bit fixated on finding a "better" solution, using the conditional but drew my self slightly into a corner. I think, in my fixation on finding an alternative approach, i didn't ask my self if it was actually needed.